# Why mark by "D" installed packages. I want only update it

Tags: list-packages

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1

```
M-x package-list-packges
```

I want to update all my installed packages. So I press "`U`". But Emacs mark many of installed package by "`D`". 
[image]

1. What does it mean? Is mean that Emacs will delete this packages. But wan't to delete it.
2. How update all installed packages?

Answer (score 4):

It's talking about the specific version of the package.

Let's look at the first `D` line there: avy. It's saying "avy version 20171230.220 is to be deleted".

Elsewhere in the buffer, you should see a later version of avy, with `I` next to it to mark the installation. Having both means the package will be upgraded.

In fact, Emacs will let you know that. When you press `x` to execute the operations, Emacs will prompt you with "Upgrade these *n* packages (pkg1-20180134, pkg2-20170813, etc)". So you've done the right thing to update packages by pressing `U`.

Comment: I update my post. So I'm not need to afraid that package will be ONLY delete because it's mark by "D". It also will be UPDATE because it's also mark by "I'. Is I'm right?

Comment: "Update" really means "delete the old version and install a newer version". So if a package has a row marked `D` and a row marked `I`, it'll be updated.

Comment: But I think if package will be mark ONLY by letter "U" it's will be not so confuse. I immediate understand that specific package has new update and will be update. I think it's better approach.

Comment: Yes, it's somewhat confusing. You can run `M-x report-emacs-bug` and write your concerns there to mail it to the Emacs devs for discussion.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that it simply means the existing version will be deleted (D) followed by downloading and installing the new version.